# Am I obligated to distinguish between morphs and megamorphs when I'm casting a card face-down?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-face-down-cards

I cast a card with megamorph and state "I'll pay {3} and morph this." Is this particular method of communication for casting a face-down creature legal? The reason I ask is because morph and megamorph mean different things.

If I control a face down creature with megamorph, and my opponent asks if it was morphed or megamorphed, am I obligated to respond? If I'm not obligated to respond, but I choose to do so, am I obligated to respond truthfully?

I know that I have to distinguish between manifests and morphs. I'm just not sure if I have to distinguish between morphs and megamorphs. Nearly all of my opponents at my Dragons of Tarkir prerelease events just said "Morph this guy." and it turned out to be a megamorph (surprise!). Given the non-existence of regular morph cards in Dragons of Tarkir, I decided to not ask a judge because I knew they were really all megamorphs. I want to know in case I run into this later.

Comment: Some form of consensus appears to have been reached - removed comments.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As long as you make it clear that you are casting the card as a 2/2 face-down creature with no text, no name, no subtypes, and no mana cost, it doesn't matter what you say. The comprehensive rules aren't specific about what you can legally *say*, and the tournament rules only say that everyone has to be clear about what's going on.

When you cast a Megamorph creature, you are casting it as a Morph creature, so there is no need to distinguish. The [Dragons of Tarkir release notes](http://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/feature/dragons-tarkir-release-notes-2015-03-18) add this to the morph rules:

> **702.36e** Megamorph is a variant of the morph ability. “Megamorph [cost]” means “**You may cast this card as a 2/2 face-down creature with no text, no name, no subtypes, and no mana cost by paying 3 rather than paying its mana cost**” and “As this permanent is turned face up, put a +1/+1 counter on it if its megamorph cost was paid to turn it face up.” A megamorph cost is a morph cost.

In addition, as Jefromi points out, the [Mechanics of Dragons of Tarkir](http://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/feature/mechanics-dragons-tarkir-2015-03-02#anchor6) says

> If you understand how morph works, megamorph is almost exactly the same. The **only difference** is that if you turn a face-down creature with megamorph face up by paying its megamorph cost, not only will it suddenly have its normal characteristics, but you'll put a +1/+1 counter on it as well!

Morph and Megamorph use the exact same wording for the bolded section, so you should just be able to say "I cast this face down" and pay {3}.

Comment: Cleared some back and forth comments that resulted in edits.

Answer (score 4):

At the prerelease we asked the tournament organiser (a DCI judge) and we were told to say "morph" whether we were casting a morph or megamorph.

Comment: Did you read his answer ? As long as everyone know's what going on it's fine. By saying morph your oponent knows it's a 2/2 with no text. I was simply pointing out a ruling by a DCI judge as the op mentions he did not ask on the prerelease

Comment: Whups, my bad, misunderstood your answer. Never mind - I might tweak it to avoid others having the same misunderstanding. (and so that I can upvote)